# How can I run a php without a web server?

Tags: php

I would like to ask if I can run a php without having installed a web server. Do I have to use the php like CGI and run my page via command line? And if so, what are the steps that I do I have to choose through the installation of php? I mean the preferences as CGI and the components after that step?

I installed the php 5.3.3 but is seems not working, I get several message that the php5ts.dll is missing and when I put that file in my ext folder other error messages appear. Are there any configuration files or steps that I have to use?
(is php 5.3.3 suitable for doing something like this?)

If I have to have a web server installed how can I run my php code through the command line?

Comment: "run my page" - If you are serving web pages why would you use anything other than a web server?

Comment: I actually want to execute a php (sorry that i said "page") that it does http request with responses,once per day automatically.(I quess i heve to make the task that wiil open the php file through the command line or just executes the php) When i run it from a browser everything goes well. When i run it without ex.apache, from php command line nothing seems to execute. (I get and the errors when  open the coomand line) what should i choose wehn i intsall php 5.3.3 (no CGI)? But i dont really found vie web what do i have to do as confuguraion so to execute php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to test PHP locally without installing a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495733/is-there-any-way-to-test-php-locally-without-installing-a-server)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You should normally be able to run a php file (after a successful installation) just by running this command:

```
$ /path/to/php myfile.php // unix way
C:\php\php.exe myfile.php // windows way
```

You can read more about running PHP in CLI mode [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php).

---

It's worth adding that PHP from version 5.4 onwards is able to run a web server on its own. You can do it by running this code in a folder which you want to serve the pages from:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

You can read more about running a PHP in a Web Server mode [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Comment: thank you for your answer(after a successful installation) thats my point i cannot have the right installation or the confuguration  for the php so to be execute i always get the errors about the php5ts.dll and then the zlib.dll... i have read so much in web about that but it dont have any result...maybe is the 5.3.3 version tha it has the problem..anyway

Comment: I see two options:
1. Try installing lower version, from 5.2.x branch (if you're ok with not having the latest features of 5.3
2. Instead of installator, use a ZIPped version, so there's no installation involved. Choose a version suitable for you from here: http://windows.php.net/download/ (you probably won't be interested in Debug Pack though)

Comment: thank you                                                          So if I understand what you say is to use the manual way installation of php. (the installer of php 5.2.8 i finally used it gives the error about the CLI dll.... when i open the command prompt) and not to use a 5.3+ version if i do this. I wiil give a try. Are there any other directions that i have to follow exept those in install.txt? i guess i follow the "Installation on Windows systems" part and "Installation of PECL extensions" part.

Comment: You might not need PECL. PHP should work as is out of the ZIP package/installer.

Comment: hello! I have add some PECL dlls as php_http.dll because my project use httpRequest. (Ι have the whole PEAR package) I read about the error message and i found out that it has to do with Oracle. But I am no going to use any oracle database in my present project and in fact not db at all. So I comment the according dll but the errors insists like a "ghost" over my php :)...

Comment: ....Another point that i remember i did in my old installation of php was to put some files in my System32 folder..(Do you know which are the correct files? i remember sure about php5ts.dll and some others)...  i have lost my old "sweet" php ..because i was advice to use the 5.3.3 and everything was destroyed...(I must have taken a backup) now i reinstall the 5.2.8 and at least i can execute php trhough a browser and apache of course...but the command prompt is not working...

Comment: I remember I used to put some mcrypt related stuff in system32 folder, but I doesn't seem to be the case lately though. It definitely wasn't any php*.dll file.

Comment: hello!!! everything looks good now, I used 5.2.14 zip package and works fine. I left the idea of 5.3.3.. and i only made the basic changes and those for the PATH according to php.net. Thank you very much..hey you may be interesting to check this out...http://www.devside.net/articles/php... bb

Comment: @MichalM How can I insert data in to database using this technique. I have to install MySQL, sql separately ??

Answer (score 8):

For windows system you should be able to run php by following below steps:

1. Download php version you want to use and put it in c:\php.
2. append ;c:\php to your system path using cmd or gui.
3. call `$ php -S localhost:8000` command in a folder which you want to serve the pages from.

Comment: it's working but how to inset data in to database by using this technique.

Comment: @subrahmanyam, You need to install Mysql separately to have database support. Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ for installing Mysql.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a normal sripting language similar to bash or python or perl. So a script with shebang works, at least on linux.

Example PHP file:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

echo("Hello World!\n")

?>
```

How to run it:

```
$ chmod 755 hello.php  # do this only once
$ ./hello.php
```

Answer (score -12):

You can use these kind of programs to emulate an apache web server and run PHP on your computer:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: well i know and i have use those two for several reasons ex joomla. But the work i  have to do now is that the file must be execute for several pcs in my net..and i would like not to install a web server on every pc..

Comment: Last time I checked, those were web servers.

Comment: Both WAMP, and XAMPP are web servers, please delete this answer.