# PHP echo in HTML

Tags: php, html, echo

I am just starting to learn PHP and I don't quite understand why it doesn't work.

I am trying a simple echo statement but nothing shows up when I open it in Chrome.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <?php
        echo "hello";
      ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this not how you test out PHP? Really confused, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need a webserver with PHP support (such as Apache httpd) and not just a browser.

Comment: Also, make sure your file ends in php, as in somepage.php.

Comment: Followed with @still_learning, Your file extension should be `.php` and should be executed/run in browser like  `http://localhost/yourfoldername/yourfilename.php`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your file isn't being parsed as PHP. I bet if you look in the source, `<?php echo "hello"; ?>` will be there, in plain text. Make sure your host supports PHP, and name your file appropriately to get it to be parsed as PHP (eg, with `.php` extension).

If you're testing this locally, you can use PHP's [built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). From command line (replacing `~/public_html` with the path to your code):

```
cd ~/public_html
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then, open `http://localhost:8000` in your browser.

Comment: May I ask what the downvote was for? Is there something incorrect in my answer?

Comment: Due to stackoverflow being evil.... I down voted the answer before you included example code, But I cant remove it because I have made to many up votes in the last hour :P

Answer (score 0):

The issue is PHP is a server side language, you need a functioning server to interpret the code and (in this case) output the appropriate HTML and CSS ~

Read more about PHP as a server side language [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php)

If you want to test your code locally you will need to use:

```
$ /path/to/php myfile.php // unix
C:\php\php.exe myfile.php // windows
```

You can read more about local web servers [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

It's worth adding that PHP from version 5.4 onwards is able to run a web server on its own. You can do it by running this code in a folder which you want to serve the pages from:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

[(Credit where credit is due)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301975/how-can-i-run-a-php-without-a-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

Save the file with php extension and open it with the help of a web server(apache)